# Change text color based on background color (e.g. in a progress bar)

Tags: ios, swift

I find it difficult to describe what I want to achieve. I looked for a picture to show:

(image link: https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/7017/screenshots/351285/button.gif)
[image]

You see that the text color of "3/4" changes to white when the bar reaches it. How can I achieve this with swift?

My idea is to have two `UIViews`, with the exact same content (except for the text color) and blend one over the other by resizing a mask or something.
The problem is that I would have to deal with duplicate content. If I wanted to change something, I would have to change it inside both `views`. Is there a more convenient way?

Thank you!

Comment: tried this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538163/inverse-uilabel-text-color-when-its-frame-intersects-an-uiview

Comment: and this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275603/uilabel-over-uiprogressview-with-multiple-colors

Comment: Wow, I googled nearly the same, except for the "intersect" part. I didn't find this. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure :-) happy coding

Comment: @UmairAfzal can we find the same for javascript